# Shifting the cube position in x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to modify the code so I can shift the cube.  The goal is to draw 3 cubes joined together and each have a different colour.  Somehow, the (0,0,0) does not shift.  (what does the (node)-- ++ (node) means?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{1}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) --  ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I do not want to use pdfplot package because of collision with other codes.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Do you like to draw a cube with specified position and color? If you like to draw many cubes you could define a new macro otherwise `\draw[red,fill=yellow,xshift=1cm]` could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you define a macro for the cube and use `scope` to shift it:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `++` in the `-- ++` syntax means that the next cordinate is an offset from the current corrrdinate.  Thus the following two are equivalent `\draw` commands:

  ```
  \draw (2,3) -- (6,8);
  \draw (2,3) -- ++(4,5);
  ```
- Note that `\pgfmathsetmacro` convertes the result to a real number whereas `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` does not. In this case it is not important but can be in other cases.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyCube}[4][]{%
    \draw[join=round,red,fill=yellow,#1] (0,0,0) -- ++(-#2,0,0) -- ++(0,-#3,0) -- ++(#2,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[join=round,red,fill=yellow,#1] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-#4) -- ++(0,-#3,0) -- ++(0,0,#4) -- cycle;
    \draw[join=round,red,fill=yellow,#1] (0,0,0) -- ++(-#2,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-#4) -- ++(#2,0,0) -- cycle;
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cubez}{1}
\begin{scope}
    \MyCube[ultra thick]{\cubex}{\cubey}{\cubez}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
    \MyCube[ultra thick,blue,fill=brown!25]{\cubex}{\cubey}{\cubez}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \MyCube[ultra thick,orange,fill=green]{\cubex}{\cubey}{\cubez}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the backslash before `shift`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{1}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) --  ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{3}
\draw[blue,fill=red] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) --  ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,fill=red] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{5}
\draw[yellow,fill=blue] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) --  ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[yellow,fill=blue] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[yellow,fill=blue] (0+\shift,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]